# Loading godaddy backup on local computer

Tags: wordpress, web

I have taken backup of my site from godaddy. Now I want to load\run my site on my local computer. Since it's a wordpress site, it comes with readme.html. That reads logical but I am not sure. If it's other procedure, do you know link to (support) article?

Note: I already talked to their "customer support" and they do not know. They gave me link to installing PHP :|

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your best bet is to use a WordPress plugin for migrating WordPress installations, once you have php, a web server, and a MariaDB or MySQL database working on your local computer.  [Search here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/migrate/). I like Duplicator, but others work too.  (I'm shocked, *shocked*, to hear GoDaddy support doesn't know. :-)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can use a service like [Local](https://localwp.com/) for running a WordPress site on your computer. It functions like other local Web Server apps like XAMPP. You start and stop it and it gives you the ability to mess around with things.